# How to compare two strings, and output the first if they're not equal

Tags: java, comparison, compare, equality, string-comparison

I have the following problem... I need to compare two string and output the first one if they are not equal. Something like the code below, but printing the first string instead. How can I do it?

```
String myString1 = new String("abc123");
String myString2 = new String("abc");
if(myString1.equals(myString2))
{
    System.out.println("The two strings are equal");
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("The two strings are not equal");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass the first string as a parameter to `System.out.println`, like this:

```
if(myString1.equals(myString2)) {
  System.out.println("The two strings are equal");
}
else {
  System.out.println(myString1);
}
```

Comment: So you just copied/pasted OP's code and changed the message on the `else` part with `myString`? I'm not sure if this is clever or is just me that I didn't understand the question (that doesn't exist).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza It seems that the OP doesn't realize that he can just pass a string variable's name to `println`. At least that's what I thought, and I'm just trying to point that out to him.

Comment: Well, at least explain what you're doing, do not post just code hoping OP can magically understand it. Note that OP doesn't even realize how to ask a question (no *?* symbol usage anywhere).

Comment: Dear Renan is the same thing but I need to out put different one cause every time String1 will change cause this comparison i will put
in a loop

Comment: @Freeman no problem. If you change the value of `myString1` between calls to `println`, everytime you execute `println` you'll print the string's current value.

Comment: Dear Renan it will give me every thing not just Different one

Comment: @Freeman: If you're changing the value held by `myString1` then this answer is good while looping. If by change every time you mean `myString1` may become `myStringN` (N being any number of `myString`s) then check out my answer, but that's not what it sounds like. If it is you could likely do it with `myString1` only or see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
String myString1 = new String("abc123");
String myString2 = new String("abc");
System.out.println("The two strings are " +
  (myString1.equals(myString2) ? "" : "not") + " equal";
```

You can also use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) for that.